# Google Docs Markup When Posting into WordPress?

Tags: google-docs, wordpress, formatting

I write in Google Docs, then paste the content into WordPress.

When I look at the HTML in WordPress, it has some extra markup added:

```
< h2 >< b >Testing< /b ></h2>
< span style="font-weight: 400;" >Test< /span >
```

I really don't want the span tags or the bold tags added.

I still want the H2 tags to be copied as well as link HTML - just not the span stuff.

Is there any way to avoid this from being copied over?

Comment: Don't know that there is a way to selectively choose the HTML that's kept. It's easy enough to not use any of it. I suggest you'd be better off using a different tool for composing.

Answer (score 1):

As a full-time blogger, I also share in this same frustration. Here are some tricks to get around this crazy issue with Google Docs and pasting into WordPress.

1. Copy and paste the contents from Google docs into your post. Then copy and paste into a new draft in WordPress, and then back again into your original document. This will clear out all the crazy formatting issues. It sounds weird, but it does work.
2. Use the free WordPress [Mammoth .docx converter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mammoth-docx-converter/) plugin.
3. Use a service called [Wordable](https://www.wordable.io/).
4. Jetpack also has a solution, along with the free [Google Docs to WordPress.com](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wordpresscom-for-google-d/baibkfjlahbcogbckhjljjenalhamjbp?hl=en) extension. (And yes, this works on self-hosted installs as well).
5. Make authors write in WordPress to begin with and bypass Google Docs.

These are explained in more depth here: https://kinsta.com/blog/google-docs-to-wordpress/

Comment: It would be better if you can add essential contents of the link into answer itself.